# Rails 3 - retrieving last accessed action/controller from current controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httpwebrequest, devise

I need to be able to set my nav on the current page depending on which page the user was perviously on.

e.g

pageX => pageA(tab1selected)
pageY => pageA(tab2selected)

I know from reading you can use request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] but I read this doesnt always get return if the user has a firewall etc

I am using devise in my app if that helps.

Is there another method ?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not a quick solution, it works:

At the end each controller **with view**, call a method to set your store your current action in the session. If you use several controllers, then create another variable for the controller.

e.g.

```
def index
  ... # your stuff
  set_action("index")
end

protected
def set_action(action_name)
  session[:action]=action_name
  #session[:controller]="my_controller_name"
end
```

You can recreate the set_action method in each controller, or make a helper and then use 2 arguments:

```
def last_visited(action_name, controller_name)
  session[:action]=action_name
  session[:controller]=controller_name
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This question was asked a long time ago, but for anyone else viewing this, my solution (though a bit of a hack) was:

```
url = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referrer)
last_controller = url[:controller]
last_action = url[:action]
```